# bq shell load a ^ delimited file

Tags: google-bigquery

We are not a able to figure out a way to push a ^ delimited file to big query using bq shell. On the UI there is an option to mention the delimiter other than ','.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Manish

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how I upload wikipedia pageviews logs to BigQuery (they are space separated, and use no quotes for strings):

```
bq load -F" "
        --quote "" \
        fh-bigquery:wikipedia.pagecounts_20140411_08 \
        pagecounts-20140411-080000.gz
        language,title,requests:integer,content_size:integer
```

`-F" "` denotes a space separated file (have a '^' instead for your use case) and `--quote ""` informs BigQuery about the non-use of quotations. Then I denote the name of the destination table, the source file, and the 5 columns this file has.

(Wikipedia pageviews dumps available here http://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pagecounts-raw/)